# Spring @Autowire annotation failing for conditional beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have JPA repository which is a conditional Bean. It will be instantiated only if we have a bean named mySqlEntityManager .

```
@ConditionalOnBean(name="mySqlEntityManager")
public interface TransactionBlobRepo extends JpaRepository<TransactionBlobData, TransactionBlobId> {    

}
```

In Service class Iam injecting this repository class using @Autowire .There its failing, throwing exceptions.
So i tried with required =false also , but it will throw NullPointerException since bean is not injected . I need to inject this bean conditionally like i did for jpa repository .
Please suggest a solution.

```
@Service
public class TransactionDaoServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    TransactionBlobRepo transactionBlobRepo;
    
    
    public void insertTransactionData(TransData data) throws SystemException{
        try {
            transactionBlobRepo.save(data); // transactionBlobRepo will be Null here if required =false
        }catch(Exception e) {
            throw new SystemException(e.getCause());
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I am confused.  Is your conditionalBean `(mysqlEntityManager) `available? Is it in the context, and your `@Autowiring` is not working?

Or the conditionalBean not configured, and not in the context, and therefore your autowire is null?

Maybe show how you are configuring the bean `mySqlEntityManager`

Comment: mysqlEntityManager bean is not available in the context , so it will throw NoSuchBeanDefinitionException error . is there a way to prevent this error without mysqlEntityManager bean ? Becuase i need to get the app running in cases where mysqlEntityManager  is not available

Comment: If the conditionalBean is not in the context, then required=false is the correct way.

However, you will then need to do ` if (transactionBlobRepo != null) {yourLogic}` so you dont get a NullPointer.

If any Bean has a Condition, it will not be wired into the context, without Condition = TRUE

Setting required=false, is telling Springboot, (Optionally wire this), and dont complain during compilation time.

However, if you do use it, and its condition == FALSE, it will be NULL.

Comment: If required = false , then the transactionBlobRepo instance will be null . But in other flow where mysqlEntityManager is available in context , at that time even though we instantiate the bean , it wont get injected since required = false . So with required = false how to inject bean manually

Comment: with mysqlEntityManager in context i need to inject transactionBlobRepo object , if mysqlEntityManager is not in context dont throw NoSuchBeanDefinitionException This is what am looking for

Comment: with required = false , If mysqlEntityManager is in context , will it autowire or not ?

Comment: Yes it will autowire